# Why is CLion giving me a warning?

Tags: c++, clion

I declared a std::priority_queue as the refernece said on CLion IDE.

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> pq;
```

Warnig says

```
Clang-Tidy: Prefer transparent functors 'greater<>'
```

and this code makes no warning.

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<>> pq;
```

I did as the reference says so:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > third (myints,myints+4);
```

Why is CLion giving me this warning and what code should I use?

Comment: Not CLion is warning, rather Clang-Tidy. There are some Clang-Tidy warnings that don't always make sense, i.e. Clang-Tidy would love to put [[nodiscard]] everywhere, or the one about shadowing variables in the case of setters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is CLion giving me this warning

The warning message explains it. Firstly, it begins with `Clang-Tidy`: This means that the suggestion is produced by the Clang-Tidy static analysis tool.

Secondly, it continues with `Prefer transparent functors`: This means that Clang-Tidy recommends that you should use transparent (comparison) functors to non-transparent ones. It also demonstrates how to declare a transparent comparison functor: `'greater<>'`.

> what code should I use?

Ideally, following Clang-Tidy's advice would be a good idea in this case, unless you're targeting old pre-C++14 systems where standard containers don't support transparent comparison functors.

While the core advantage of transparent functors, that is avoiding construction of large objects of element type upon lookup doesn't apply (because `int` is tiny and fast to construct), transparent functors  avoid unnecessary repetition of the element type, which improves maintainability.

For more detailed information and rationale about the subject, see [this standard proposal (n3421)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.htm) about transparent functors, [this proposal (n3465)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3465.pdf) about heterogeneous lookup, [and this one (n3657)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3657.htm) which essentially revises n3465 with the help of n3421.

Answer (score 1):

This page
https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/modernize-use-transparent-functors.html
contains the following answer:

> When using transparent functors, the type does not need to be
>   repeated. The code is easier to read, maintain and less prone to
>   errors. It is not possible to introduce unwanted conversions.

Therefore use the transparent functor.